# Proving $|\sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ z_{ k } } |=\sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ |z_{ k }| } \Longleftrightarrow \arg(z_1)=\arg(z_2)=\cdots=\arg(z_n) $

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose $z_1,\dots, z_n$ are $n$ elements from $\mathbb{C}^*$.

How can I prove that $|\sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ z_{ k } } |=\sum _{ k=1 }^{ n }{ |z_{ k }| } \Longleftrightarrow \arg(z_1)=\arg(z_2)=\cdots=\arg(z_n) $ .

Comment: zs are complex numbers

Comment: $|1+2|=|1|+|2|,$  but $1  \neq 2.$  Note that $1,2$   are   complex numbers.

Comment: The conclusion of the implication is not that the radii coincide but that the angles do.

Comment: sorry I did a big mistake when I was writing this post. forget all what I wrote

Comment: This isn't really a complex number problem, it's a geometry problem.  The shortest distance to a point is a straight line.  If the angles of the vectors aren't equal, then the distance will be longer than the shortest distance because the path isn't straight.  Add formality as necessary.

Answer (score 5):

When $z_k=r_k e^{i\phi}$ then $\sum_k z_k=e^{i\phi}\sum_k r_k$ and therefore
$$\left|\sum\nolimits_k z_k\right|=\left|\sum\nolimits_k r_k\right|=\sum\nolimits_k r_k=\sum\nolimits_k |z_k|\ .$$
Conversely, when $z_1z_2\ne0$ and $\arg(z_1)\ne\arg(z_2)$ then $|z_1+z_2|<|z_1|+|z_2|$. It follows that
$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n z_k\right|\leq |z_1+z_2|+\sum_{k=3}^n|z_k|<\sum_{k=1}^n |z_k|\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to prove the following statement :

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$ and $(z_{1},\ldots,z_{n}) \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ such that :
>
> $$ \Big\vert \sum_{k=1}^{n} z_{k} \Big\vert = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \vert z_{k} \vert $$
>
> Then, there exists $\theta \in [0,2\pi[$ such that : $\forall k \in \left\{ 1,\ldots,n \right\}, \; z_{i} = \vert z_{i} \vert e^{i \theta}$.

**Hints** :

1. Prove that for all $(i,j) \in \left\{ 1,\ldots,n \right\}^{2}, \; i \neq j, \; \mathrm{Re}(z_{i}\overline{z_{j}}) = \vert z_{i} \vert \vert z_{j} \vert$
   You just have to show that :
   $$ \Bigg( \Big\vert \sum_{k=1}^{n} z_{k} \Big\vert^{2} = \Big( \sum_{k=1}^{n} \vert z_{k} \vert \Big)^{2} \Bigg) \Rightarrow \Bigg( \sum_{\substack{1 \leq i,j \leq n \\ i < j}} \mathrm{Re}(z_{i}\overline{z_{j}}) - \vert z_{i} \vert \vert z_{j} \vert = 0 \Bigg) $$
2. Show that there exists $\theta \in [0,2\pi[$ such that $z_{k} = \vert z_{k} \vert e^{i\theta}$ for all $k \in \left\{ 1,\ldots,n \right\}$.

You need to prove that if $z_{i} = \vert z_{i} \vert e^{i\theta_{i}}$ and $z_{j} = \vert z_{j} \vert e^{i \theta_{j}}$ with $\theta_{i},\theta_{j} \in [0,2\pi[$, then :
$$ \Big( \mathrm{Re}(z_{i}\overline{z_{j}}) = \vert z_{i} \vert \vert z_{j} \vert \Big) \Rightarrow \Big( \cos(\theta_{i} - \theta_{j}) = 0 \Big) $$